# Calculation of a normal force with an angle

Tags: gravity, forces

I'm currently studying forces in physics and in this example, it states that *Fn +Fay = mg*. Why is this so? Is it because they are both in the same direction?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That equation expresses the fact that the forces on the block in the vertical direction add up to zero. $F_n$ and $F_{ay}$ are both forces pulling the block upwards, while the force of gravity on the block is $mg$ downwards. We don't want the block to accelerate up or down, and so the net forces in the vertical direction must cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Fn is the normal reaction force and Fay is the y-component of the force Fa, since the block is not moving in the y-direction (+ve or -ve) and since we know that mg is acting downwards, there has to be some force(s) balancing out mg, and apart from the normal reaction, Fay is also acting upwards, so yea it's Fn + Fay = mg because both Fn and Fay are acting in the same direction where as mg is acting in the opposite direction.